# PHP limit rows and columns per page

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have 300+ records.

```
id | name | last_name                | gender 
-----------------------------------------------
1  | John | Doe                      | Male
2  | Jane | Smith Dolores Clayborne  | Female
3  | Paul | Paulson                  | Male
.
.
.
300 | Jake | Jacob                   | Male
```

I want to display it in my table that has 5 columns and 50 rows each page. so next page will show another rcolumns and 50 records.

my code below

```
$req = "SELECT * FROM  `directory` "; 

$query = mysql_query($req);

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $row['name'];
}
echo '</table>';
```

this query will show 300 records in one column

i just need to show it on 5 column.

supposed to be the result below would be:

```
<table>
<tr><td>VALUE1</td><td>VALUE2</td><td>VALUE3</td><td>VALUE4</td><td>VALUE5</td></tr>
<tr><td>VALUE6</td><td>VALUE7</td><td>VALUE8</td><td>VALUE9</td><td>VALUE10</td></tr>
<tr><td>VALUE11</td><td>VALUE12</td><td>VALUE13</td><td>VALUE14</td><td>VALUE15</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve. I don't see the correlation between the db and the table. The order does not make sense.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code, and provide more details and it will be easier to help.

Comment: This appears to be a question about simple pagination.

Comment: well something like that.. records will show 5 columns and 50 rows per page.. supposed i have 300 records my my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

```
echo '<table>';
$i = 0;
$close = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{   
    if($i%50 == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
        $close += 5;
    }

    echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';

    if($i == $close)
        echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

A general answer: In order to print the fields: `name`, `last_name`, ... just get the rows from de database -  using PDO for instance - inside a variable `$rows`, and then iterate through `$rows` and get the values inside a double-dimension array `$rows_array`. Finally, you just have to iterate and print the data from the double-dimension array.

To get the column names, just execute the query

```
"SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename"
```

Hope that helps,
PD: Thanks to the previous editor for improving the format of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CEILING(a.id/5) rowNo, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id%5=1 THEN a.name ELSE '' END) col1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id%5=2 THEN a.name ELSE '' END) col2, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id%5=3 THEN a.name ELSE '' END) col3, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id%5=4 THEN a.name ELSE '' END) col4, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.id%5=0 THEN a.name ELSE '' END) col5
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY CEILING(a.id/5)
```